# line breaks and spaces in XML Schematron

Tags: java, xml, schematron

I have a problem. I have linebreaks and spaces and tabs in XML. Like this:

```
<value xs:type="DV_TEXT"><value>1111\this is what it is used for, this could be a   
really long line or even
multiple lines, just like
what you are reading now
</value></value>
```

The setTextContent and getTextContent in Java from org.w3c.dom deal just fine with it. No problem.

But now, I am generating Schematron for validation to check if this string really appears in the value.  The Schematron is generated from a definition file in which the test-strings are configurated

The generated Schematron, the assert-test looks like this:

```
test="(matches(.,'1111\this is what it is used for, this could be a really long line or even&#xD;&#xA;multiple lines, just like&#xD;&#xA;what you are reading now'))"
```

And then when I validate, there are more problems coming up.
First the linebreaks. It seems that in the definition-file from which the Schematron is generated there are `\r\n` instead of only `\n`.
But well, I have to count on that. If I replace all `&#xD;&#xA;` with only `&#xA;` some of the errors are disappeared. And how can I be sure that the XML-file also has only `&#xA;` as linebreak?

I think I need to alter the string which comes in the test asserts, and, for example, replace all `\r\n` with only `\n`.

I have done that, and it solves partly my problem. What else should I think about?

All tips are welcome.

Comment: "And how can I be sure that the XML-file also has only `&#xA;` as linebreak" - [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends) an XML parser must always normalize line endings to U+000A when reading an XML file, whatever the original file contained.  The only U+000D characters you should see are those that were represented as character references in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the node text to be valid regardless of its *whitespace* use the **[normalize-space function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)** function:

> The normalize-space function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space. [...]

So, this should work:

```
test="(matches(normalize-space(.),'1111\this is what it is used for, this could be a really long line or even multiple lines, just like what you are reading now'))
```